# Crystal Reports Wrapping Text Field from Dataset

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, dataset, word-wrap

I'm working with crystal reports and visual studio 2010 to show a reports from sql server database. So i have this large text field (varchar(500)) and retrieved it with dataset to generate the reports. The problem is, the text field on my report instead of wrapping the text to fit the box, it cuts off on the right hand side and does not bring it down a line. I did not see any design time properties that looked like they directly affected the text wrapping function. What i have done so far :

1. I have use the can grow option and set the approciate limit, but it still overlaping the line.
2. I Also have try to insert the datafield inside text object, but nothing changed.

The screenshot is here http://imageshack.us/f/11/44079942.jpg/

What am I missing?

Thankyou in advance

pe2s

Comment: In crystal report take the field and right click the field and check property. in which they give the wrap option select that. If this not working then put your crystal report screen shot

Comment: i'm sorry , but i can't find any wrap option on the field properties, can you be more clear ? this is the screenshot of my cr http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/11/44079942.jpg/, i'm sorry i can't upload it here since i still don't have the reputation , thanks

Comment: Oh. you need to adjust your field. Try to put field on top and increase it's height and reduce the width. There is no direct wrap option in it. You need to set font and paragraph setting into Format editor of the field.

Comment: done that, already reduce the width and height, nothing happened, still surpass the other field

Comment: Are these spaces between words or some other (invisible) characters (chr(160), chr(255) etc)? I have seen CR wrapping gone wrong with unusual symbols in field values (although in opposite way).
Then, in section properties, make sure that "free-form placement" is checked.

Answer (score 9):

Right click on the text field, select 'format object', go to the common tab, and check "Can Grow".  This allows the textbox to grow down as the text wraps.

Comment: done that already , and nothing happened, i checked the "can grow" format and set the value to 0,its still surpass the line, even when i reduce the width of my textfield

Answer (score 5):

Try this,

1. Right click the field you want to word wrap
2. Select "Format Object" option
3. select "Can Grow" checkbox
4. Maximum number of lines "1" or keep it "0" to ignore line limit.

This should work..

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

Right click the object
Select Format Object
select Can Grow
Maximum number of lines "0"
then ok

Answer (score 0):

I have already solved it, it turn out that my Crystal reports seems to be crashed. When i reinstall my CR13 the problem dissapeared. Thank You for all your repply